# How do you write a program to automatically modify existing SQL database every x minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am a PHP/SQL novice user....Finishing off my first PHP website. The question is similar to the initial question found at:

http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/266235-modifying-database-after-a-set-time-limit/

but I did not completely understand the answer. Similar to that user, I have an entire column (called *status*) of a database (called *challenge*) that can take 3 values for *status* - 'inactive', 'pending', or 'active'. In the normal flow of website operations, User A will typically click a button (**event 1**) which creates a new row (with a unique *challenge_id*) in the database and triggers a *status* of 'pending' in that row. User B can change the *status* with other clicked buttons, which can set the *status* to 'inactive' or 'active'.

One undesirable scenario is where USER B does nothing (i.e., no event trigger). In this case, User A is unfortunately stuck, waiting for the *status* to change from 'pending' to either 'active' or 'inactive' before he/she can click and trigger the next **event 1**. This situation could occur for example if User B gets tired of the site and does not use it anymore, leaving 'pending' requests unanswered.

Clearly, I can manually alter the SQL, changing any 'pending' status to 'inactive' after a certain time limit. This would be fine at the beginning, but if the site ever became popular, this would take more time. Is there any way to write a non-PHP program to account for this 'no event trigger' scenario where all 'pending' status SQL entries are automatically altered after a certain time limit? Or can PHP do this? I tried writing a php script that would sweep the database every time **any** user logged in (note: *challenge_id* is created by an event triggered on a different PHP page):

```
<?php session_start();

if ((($_SESSION['role']) != SHA1('user')) && (($_SESSION['status']) != SHA1('active')))     
{
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
session_destroy();
} else 


include 'connect.php';

$_SESSION['login_id'];

$universaltime = time();

$sqlt = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT challenge.challengetime, 
challenge.status FROM challenge"); //Selects an array of all values for challengetime 
//and status for all users I presume


while ((($universaltime - $sqlt['challengetime']) > 1000) && 
($sqlt['status'] == 'pending'))   
{

$sqlt1 = mysqli_query("UPDATE challenge SET $sqlt['status'] ='inactive'"); 
//Also tried with if instead of while

}



?>
```

I'm sure my code can be improved...any help would be appreciated greatly! Or do I need to use something other than PHP?

Comment: store an expiration date and not a status?

Comment: Why are you using `sha1()` there? Your session variables are private anyway, so shouldn't require a one-way hashing in the first place unless hackers have constant access to your system and even then it solves the wrong problem.

Comment: What data type is `challengetime` in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all** your `UPDATE` statement is wrong. Assuming that `challengetime` is of int data type holding unix time values your UPDATE statements should look something like this

```sql
UPDATE challenge 
   SET status = 'inactive'
 WHERE status = 'pending' 
   AND 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - challengetime;
```

It can be and should be run on its own. You don't need to select anything prior to calling it.
Therefore you can change this part

```
$universaltime = time();
$sqlt = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT challenge.challengetime, 
challenge.status FROM challenge"); //Selects an array of all values for challengetime 
//and status for all users I presume
while ((($universaltime - $sqlt['challengetime']) > 1000) && 
($sqlt['status'] == 'pending'))   
{
$sqlt1 = mysqli_query("UPDATE challenge SET $sqlt['status'] ='inactive'"); 
//Also tried with if instead of while
}
```

with just

```
$sql = "UPDATE challenge SET status = 'inactive' WHERE status = 'pending' AND 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - challengetime";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO better error handling
}
```

---

Now to make it execute periodically on it own you don't necessarily need php. You can:

**First option** Use [MySQL event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).
To execute this statement every day at 11pm

```sql
CREATE EVENT change_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
   STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 23 HOUR 
DO 
  UPDATE challenge 
     SET status = 'inactive'
   WHERE status = 'pending' 
     AND 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - challengetime;
```

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to check if event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
More on configuring event scheduler [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

**Second option** Use crontab to invoke CLI `mysql`

```sql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uuser -ppassword -e " UPDATE challenge SET status = 'inactive' WHERE status = 'pending' AND 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - challengetime"
```

Comment: Thank you peterm...I tried your php code and it worked like a charm. Conceptually I knew something like your solution was the correct solution, but I just couldn't generate the correct code. Your code worked perfectly....I am going to study your 'First Option' for the periodic implementation of the MySQL event.

Comment: By the way, for your 'First Option', once "event_scheduler" has been set to "on" and I have SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; can your 'First Option' code be included in the same php file as your php solution above, or must this code be written in SQL?

Comment: @TheBewilderedChemist You're quite welcome. I'm glad I could help :) There is no need to put event creation code in php. Just execute it in phpMyAdmin, or mysql command line utility (or any other mysql client for that matter) like any other CREATE statement in MySQL (e.g. like `CREATE TABLE`). You can list existing events with `SHOW EVENTS`.

Answer (score 0):

If your web & PHP server is running on Linux (which is often the case) and if the delay *x* is more than a few minutes (i.e. *x>=5 minutes*) then you could use [crontab(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) and add a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry. Remember to use absolute paths there. That entry would run (periodically) some script (which you could code in PHP, but also in some other scripting language like Python or OCaml) which would update the MySQL database.